# Attaching tooltip text to tooltip container

Tags: css, tooltip

I have a document with tooltip and tooltiptext classes. When I define a <a:> or <span> with class=tooltip, the tooltip text appear above the enclosing <p> container rather than directly above the text.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang=en>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <TITLE>favorite things</TITLE>
        <META name="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="filk">
        <style>
            p        {
                       left:20%;
                       position:relative;
                       right:-20%;
                       text-indent:2em;
                       width:60%;
                     }

            p.drop   {
                       text-indent:2em;
                     }

            p.drop::first-letter  {
                       font-size:2em;
                       text-indent:-2em;
                     }

            a.L,div.L,span.L {
                       display:inline;
                       width:14%;
                       position:absolute;
                       left:-20%;
                     }

            a.R,div.R,span.R {
                       display:inline;
                       width:14%;
                       position:absolute;
                       right:00%;
                     }


            h1       {
                       text-align:center;
                       font-size:4em;
                     }


            img.V    {
                       display:block;
                       margin:10% 10% 10% 10%;
                       max-width:90%;
                       width:100%;
                     }


           /* Tooltip container */
          .tooltip {
            border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
          }

          /* Tooltip text */
          .tooltip .tooltiptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 120px;
            background-color: #555;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px 0;
            border-radius: 6px;

            /* Position the tooltip text */
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            bottom: 102%;
            left: 10%;
            margin-left: -40px;
            Min-width: 20em;
            max-width: 70em;

            /* Fade in tooltip */
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 0.3s;
          }

          .L .tooltiptext {
            left: 10%;
            text-align: left;
          }

          .R  .tooltiptext {
            left: -50%;
            text-align: left;
          }

          /* Tooltip arrow */
          /*
            left: 15%;
          */
          .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -5px;
            border-width: 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
          }

          .L .tooltiptext::after {
            left: 15%;
          }

          .R .tooltiptext::after {
            left: 30%;
          }

          /* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
          .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
          }

          .verse     {
            font-size: 2em;
            text-align: center;
            width:60%
          }
        </style>
</head>
<BODY LANG="en-US" DIR="LTR">
<H1>My favorite things</H1>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<p class="drop verse">
Gardening
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungoliant">
   spiders
   <span class=tooltiptext>
     Ungoliant, who took the form of a giant spider and, along with Dark Lord Melkor, destroyed the Two Trees of Valinor
   </span>
</a>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silmarillion">
<img class=V src="../Images/Silmarillion.png"
             alt="The Silmarillion">
</a>
<br>
<a class=R href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring">
<img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8e/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring_cover.gif"
             alt="The Fellowship of the Ring">
</a>
And
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth_weapons_and_armour#Narsil">
  swords that are broken
  <span class=tooltiptext>
     Elendil&apos;s sword Narsil, called <q>The Sword that was Broken</q> after
     its damage in a battle against Sauron, and later caried by
     Aragorn (<q>Strider</q>).
  </span>
</a>
<br>
Words in the
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Speech">
  Black Speech
  <span class=tooltiptext>
    The Black Speech of Mordor is a language constructed by Sauron.
  </span>
</a>
<br>
That must not be spoken
<br>
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denethor">
  Unfaithful stewards
  <span class=tooltiptext>
    Denethor, the 26th ruling Steward of Gondor.
  </span>
</a>
<br>
<a class="L tooltip" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_the_King">
  <img class=V src="../Images/81UzbZbGPUL._SL1500_.jpg"
               alt="The Return of the King">
  <span class=tooltiptext>
    Denethor, the 26th ruling Steward of Gondor.
  </span>
</a>
Who don't want their kings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

A secondary issue is that the arrow is too wide

I tried making .tooltip display: inline-block, but that introduced extraneous spaces into the rendering.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang=en>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <TITLE>favorite things</TITLE>
        <META name="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="filk">
        <style>
            p        {
                       left:20%;
                       position:relative;
                       right:-20%;
                       text-indent:2em;
                       width:60%;
                     }

            p.drop   {
                       text-indent:2em;
                     }

            p.drop::first-letter  {
                       font-size:2em;
                       text-indent:-2em;
                     }

            a.L,div.L,span.L {
                       display:inline;
                       width:14%;
                       position:absolute;
                       left:-20%;
                     }

            a.R,div.R,span.R {
                       display:inline;
                       width:14%;
                       position:absolute;
                       right:00%;
                     }


            h1       {
                       text-align:center;
                       font-size:4em;
                     }


            img.V    {
                       display:block;
                       margin:10% 10% 10% 10%;
                       max-width:90%;
                       width:100%;
                     }


           /* Tooltip container */
          .tooltip {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
          }

          /* Tooltip text */
          .tooltip .tooltiptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 120px;
            background-color: #555;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px 0;
            border-radius: 6px;

            /* Position the tooltip text */
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            bottom: 102%;
            left: 10%;
            margin-left: -40px;
            Min-width: 20em;
            max-width: 70em;

            /* Fade in tooltip */
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 0.3s;
          }

          .L .tooltiptext {
            left: 10%;
            text-align: left;
          }

          .R  .tooltiptext {
            left: -50%;
            text-align: left;
          }

          /* Tooltip arrow */
          /*
            left: 15%;
          */
          .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -5px;
            border-width: 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
          }

          .L .tooltiptext::after {
            left: 15%;
          }

          .R .tooltiptext::after {
            left: 30%;
          }

          /* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
          .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
          }

          .verse     {
            font-size: 2em;
            text-align: center;
            width:60%
          }
        </style>
</head>
<BODY LANG="en-US" DIR="LTR">
<H1>My favorite things</H1>

<p>
[Verse]
</p>
<p class="drop verse">
Gardening
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungoliant">
   spiders
   <span class=tooltiptext>
     Ungoliant, who took the form of a giant spider and, along with Dark Lord Melkor, destroyed the Two Trees of Valinor
   </span>
</a>
<a class=L href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silmarillion">
<img class=V src="../Images/Silmarillion.png"
             alt="The Silmarillion">
</a>
<br>
<a class=R href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring">
<img class=V src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8e/The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring_cover.gif"
             alt="The Fellowship of the Ring">
</a>
And
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth_weapons_and_armour#Narsil">
  swords that are broken
  <span class=tooltiptext>
     Elendil&apos;s sword Narsil, called <q>The Sword that was Broken</q> after
     its damage in a battle against Sauron, and later caried by
     Aragorn (<q>Strider</q>).
  </span>
</a>
<br>
Words in the
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Speech">
  Black Speech
  <span class=tooltiptext>
    The Black Speech of Mordor is a language constructed by Sauron.
  </span>
</a>
<br>
That must not be spoken
<br>
<a class=tooltip href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denethor">
  Unfaithful stewards
  <span class=tooltiptext>
    Denethor, the 26th ruling Steward of Gondor.
  </span>
</a>
<br>
<a class="L tooltip" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_the_King">
  <img class=V src="../Images/81UzbZbGPUL._SL1500_.jpg"
               alt="The Return of the King">
  <span class=tooltiptext>
    Denethor, the 26th ruling Steward of Gondor.
  </span>
</a>
Who don't want their kings
<br>
These are a few of
<br>
My favorite things.
</p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why, but it appears that it is the `text-indent` that is triggering the problem; changing it to `margin-left` resolves the problem.